# Python: Why does this AttributeError in __str__ method disappear after this indentation change

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, indentation, instance-methods

I hope you will be able to replicate this error on your machine. I couldn't figure out why exactly the code below gave me an error [pasted thereafter] when I had the `__str__` method aligned with the same indentation as the methods: `__init__` and `addNeighbor`. I had written part of the class from this [link](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Graphs/Implementation.html) but named my variables in `__str__` differently. When I got the error, I just pasted the code from the link and it worked.

It was at this point that I realized that my indentation for the `__str__` method was not inline with that of the other methods. When I put everything into the same indentation, I had the same error so I returned the method into its prior implementation and got this output: `<__main__.Vertex object at 0x1079b4128>` Why is this the case? Shouldn't I have gotten an `IndentationError` from the beginning? When I indent my own version of the `__str__` method and give it more of an indentation, I don't get any error. Why? Can anyone replicate this error?

```
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, key):
    self.id = key
    self.connectedTo = {}

  def addNeighbor(self, neighbor, weight=0):
    self.connectedTo[neighbor] = weight

    def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id) + " connected to: " + str([vertex.id for vertex in self.connectedTo])

    # def __str__(self):
    #   return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  vertex = Vertex(1)
  vertex.addNeighbor('1', 20)
  vertex.addNeighbor('2', 10)
  print(vertex)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graph_implementation.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(vertex)
  File "graph_implementation.py", line 13, in __str__
    return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])
  File "graph_implementation.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

First of all, as you said, your indentation of `__str__` is wrong. But it's still a *valid* indentation, which is why you wouldn't get an `IndentationError`. The error only appears when `__str__` gets called, which only happens when it's at the correct indentation level, which is the lesser indentation, in line with `__init__` and `addNeighbor`. (Otherwise, it's just a local function inside `addNeighbor`, and pretty useless.)

Once the `__str__` method is being called, the error you are getting is because of the structure of the `self.connectedTo` dictionary. In `addNeighbor()` you are mapping `neighbor: weight`, where `neighbor` is getting passed in as a `str` and weight as an `int`. When you iterate through a dictionary as in `[x.id for x in self.connectedTo]`, Python will iterate through the *keys* of that dictionary, which in this case is `neighbor`, a string. So `x` becomes a string. (The list comprehension is better written as `[x.id for x in self.connectedTo.keys()]`, which is equivalent to the original but clearer.)

The page you linked shows the original mistake, though – namely that `neighbor` should be another `Vertex`, not a `str`. Meaning it all boils down to passing the wrong type of argument into `addNeighbor()`. So with that in mind, I might rewrite your test code like this...

```
class Vertex:
  def __init__(self, key):
    self.id = key
    self.connectedTo = {}

  def addNeighbor(self, neighbor, weight=0):
    self.connectedTo[neighbor] = weight

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  vertex = Vertex(1)
  vertex.addNeighbor(Vertex(1), 20) # This creates a second Vertex with the same ID
                                    # as `vertex` -- probably not what you intend?
  vertex.addNeighbor(Vertex(2), 10)
  print(vertex)


# Output:
1 connected to: [1, 2]
```

Comment: How would I call `__str__` method if is within `addNeighbor`?

Comment: Basically, you don't. It would be a local function, stored in the local namespace inside `addNeighbor`, and so just like any other local variable, it's only available within the method itself. I suppose you could get around this by declaring it a `global` variable, but this would be an enormously bad practice, and wouldn't even gain you anything for your trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This is because with the indentation that you have, `__str__` is a local function within the method `addNeighbor`. It is visible only in the scope of `addNeighbor`. In the absence of the user-defined `__str__`, the default method is used.

The original error happened because the `x` in `x.id` is a string (the node name). Strings do not have an `id` attribute. For your code to work, change `vertex.addNeighbor('1', 20)` and the like to `vertex.addNeighbor(Vertex('1'), 20)`.

Comment: Thanks. This is the second time I am learning something new from Python by accident. I didn't realize that the output wasn't even what I wanted to be printed. I was just happy I didn't get an error. I didn't know one could have local methods within the scope of another method. How would you call the local method __str__ within the scope of __addNeighbor__?

Comment: You would call it as `__str__(self)`, but it makes little sense.

Comment: Without any indication of `addNeighbor`?